# What is the best way to install LAMP on Linux Mint

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lamp

I am running Linux Mint 17 Rebecca. Is there a package that installs and configures these, or do they need to be installed and configured separately?

Comment: Most of the time, the installer will ask you for something like "Web Configuration", and will give you Apache, mySQL and PHP (along with other goodies like Perl) automagically.  Otherwise, just do a couple of "apt-get's".  Here's a good link: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd seen the link you gave me before. I was more wondering if there is a recommended apt-get install "bundle" that would install the latest and greatest of the 4 components.

Comment: Please, if any of the answers were useful, accept it or close the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any packages (although, there might be some) that does that for you but this simple one-liner should do it for you:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server-5.6 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Be aware that it also installs other packages as well. If you do not want them, you would have to compile from source && install.

**Update**

Archlinux User Repository has one: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xampp/. IMHO, it has to be tweaked for Mint.

Comment: I will look into this. I stumbled upon this as well and it may fit my needs. I needed something to install as a package as part of our default provisioning and I wanted a script or a package that techs could just run as a part of spinning up the builds.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple option: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` (notice the ending `^`)...But this is a pretty broad question with multiple answers.

Comment: Thank you this is what is available as a 'bundle' and answers my broad question.